# How to use MongoDB Compass' generated pipeline in C# to run aggregation pipeline

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I used MongoDB's Compass to created a pipeline that I exported to C#, however I am not sure how to use this (tool generates a BsonArray) in the actual code to perform an aggregation? This is a geoNear which isn't currently supported by LINQ, if that has any bearing.

I attempted to use this `var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline);` which [some documentation](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c) suggested (pipeline - is that BsonArray object generated by Compass.

**Example of what compass would create:**

```
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$geoNear",
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "near",
    new BsonDocument
            {
                { "type", "Point" },
                { "coordinates",
    new BsonArray
                {
                    -2.11,
                    52.55
                } }
            } },
            { "distanceField", "distanceField" },
            { "maxDistance", 5000 },
            { "spherical", true }
        }),
    new BsonDocument("$sort",
    new BsonDocument("distanceField", -1))
};
```

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712478/4368485) for a convenient approach.

Comment: that was my initial approach but sadly I couldn't get that to work

Comment: did you use MongoDB.Entities library? update your question with the compass generated code so that we can get an idea of your requirement.

Comment: i dont have it to hand right now, but the general problem is described above, simply how do you use that to send a request for aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that using the compass generated code just needed to be strongly typed. For some reason the compiler could not interpret what was going on (contrary to [original code idea](https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/mongodb-aggregation-framework-examples-in-c). So instead of using var a type was required. Seems so trivial now...

so as an example:

```
 PipelineDefinition<Transport, Transport> pipeline= new BsonArray
    {
        new BsonDocument("$geoNear",
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "near",
        new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "type", "Point" },
                    { "coordinates",
        new BsonArray
                    {
                        -2.11,
                        52.55
                    } }
                } },
                { "distanceField", "distanceField" },
                { "maxDistance", 5000 },
                { "spherical", true }
            }),
        new BsonDocument("$sort",
        new BsonDocument("distanceField", -1))
    };


 //this will now work
 var cursor = await collection.AggregateAsync(pipeline);
 var listResult = await cursor.ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 5):

Somehow the currently accepted answer did not worked for me as my compiler says it cannot cast BsonArray to PipelineDefinition, but it led me to a solution that worked for me.

```
PipelineDefinition<Transport, Transport> pipeline= new []
    {
        new BsonDocument("$geoNear",
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "near",
        new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "type", "Point" },
                    { "coordinates",
        new BsonArray
                    {
                        -2.11,
                        52.55
                    } }
                } },
                { "distanceField", "distanceField" },
                { "maxDistance", 5000 },
                { "spherical", true }
            }),
        new BsonDocument("$sort",
        new BsonDocument("distanceField", -1))
    };


 //this will now work
 var cursor = await collection.AggregateAsync(pipeline);
 var listResult = await cursor.ToListAsync();
```

Basically, it wanted a BsonDocument[] instead of a BsonArray

Answer (score 0):

give this no bsondocument, no magic strings solution a try. change the `Cafe` class to match your domain entity.

```cs
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Entities; // Install-Package MongoDB.Entities

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Cafe : Entity
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Coordinates2D Location { get; set; }
            public double distanceField { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // connect to mongodb
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            // define an index
            DB.Index<Cafe>()
              .Key(c => c.Location, KeyType.Geo2DSphere)
              .Create();

            // define a search point
            var searchPoint = new Coordinates2D(-2.11, 52.55);

            // initial query
            var query = DB.GeoNear<Cafe>(
                                NearCoordinates: searchPoint,
                                DistanceField: c => c.distanceField,
                                MaxDistance: 50000,
                                Spherical: true)
                          .SortByDescending(c => c.distanceField);

            // add another stage to above query
            var coffeeBeans = query.Match(c => c.Name == "Coffee Bean");

            // retrieve entities
            var result = coffeeBeans.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```